# Link <img> in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an image like this

```
<input type="file" name="pic_file" id="photo_file">
<img id="image_holder" src="" />
```

The `<img>` source is set by the user, though a file input as seen in above code. I want the img to be linked with an `<a>` but since the I have not saved the image yet I cant put a relative link to the full size image. How could I use the cached version of the image that is being displyed and use that as a link that would be something like this

```
 <a href="cached_img with id=image_holder"><img id="image_holder" src="" /></a>
```

The user woudl have uploaded an image at this point so the src woudl not be empty

Thanks

Comment: `<a href="#"><img src=" /></a>`? And then do whatever javascript you need?

Comment: ***since the I have not save and dont want to save the image to the server*** - So where will it go then? In order to link to it, it must he stored somewhere.

Comment: @DanWhite I am saving it to a database, I am wondering if without getting it from that database, since it has to be saved on the current page somewhere, can I use that to display it, do you know what I mean?

Comment: Then read up on BLOB - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: @DanWhite I know how to save and what to save it as, but I am saying it has not been saved until the user clicks the final submit, so can I show it full screen cause it must be cached somewhere on the current page

Comment: Then yes. Yes you can. Now, unless you are going to show us what you have done (code), what you can't make work, etc, there's nothing we can do to help. We are not a free coding service and I care very little for guessing what you want from a badly explained question.

Comment: @aug could you help me, I have updated question with more details, I am not sure how to reference the version that has been cached on the page, and is being displayed by the `<img id="image_holder" src="" />`

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded | Next time do a little research. It took me less than 5 secs to find it.

Comment: So with the updated question, can I assume that you have tried nothing whatsoever?

Comment: @icecub that is not what I am trying to achieve, after the image has been input by the user I would like to it be clickable and when clicked go to a full screen of that image

Comment: @DanWhite Im really not sure how to access the cached version at all?

Comment: So make a javascript function that enlarges it to full screen? It's not like we want to be rude to you, seriously. But @DanWhite is right. We're not here to do your job for you. We're here if you have a specific issue with your code. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site **for professional and enthusiast programmers.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in JavaScript:

```
var photofile = document.getElementById("photo_file");

photofile.onchange = function(){
    if (photofile.files && photofile.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var result = e.target.result;
            photofile.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<a href='" + result + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + result + "' id='image_holder'/></a>");
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }    
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JacquesMarais/sme1p1vm/)..

When an image is selected, this will show the image in an `<img>` tag, with a link that will open the image in a new tab when clicked.

Comment: Honestly.. you are way to kind! ;-)

Comment: For doing his job for him :P